# Retaining Decimal 0 during mysql outfile

Tags: mysql, into-outfile

So I have a table structure like so,

```
CREATE TABLE DATA_0 (ID BIGINT(15), I_R_A int(10) DEFAULT NULL, I_NO varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, V_x double(10,1) DEFAULT NULL);
```

With sample data like so,

```
ID,I_R_A,I_NO,V_x
1,10000,9895987650, 10000.0
2,60,2424, 60.0
3,70,34, 70.0
4,80,34245, 80.0
```

When executing following outfile query-

```
SELECT ID,I_R_A,I_NO,V_x INTO OUTFILE "/home/user/out.txt" FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' FROM DATA_0;
```

My output file looks like this-

```
ID,I_R_A,I_NO,V_x
1,10000,9895987650, 10000
2,60,2424, 60
3,70,34, 70
4,80,34245, 80
```

As you can see the **decimal 0** has been **removed** from the **column** `V_x`. How can I retain this **0**?

Comment: You can’t “retain” what did not even exist to begin with. Real numbers don’t have trailing zeroes after the decimal point. If you want one nevertheless, then you will have to implement that yourself, write an appropriate “casting” function to use in that place, that transforms your number value into the _string_ format you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function

```
SELECT ID,I_R_A,I_NO, REPLACE(FORMAT(V_x, 1), ',', '')
INTO OUTFILE "/home/user/out.txt" 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
FROM DATA_0;
```

Comment: `FORMAT` will include a comma (,) within the 10000 to separate the
thousands, If that is not what you want you need to use `REPLACE(FORMAT(V_x, 1), ',', '')` instead.

Comment: @Edward happy to help you :)